# plotting air pollution data over UK using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a data with 3 vectors, (Lat, Long and  pollutant concentration). I want to plot the pollutant concentrations with UK map in background in differnt colors including a colorbar .
Is there an easy way to do that?
I am trying to use the geoshow function , but how to vary the marker colour based on concentration?
Please help,Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks..SSR

Here is my code

```
clear all; close all;
S = shaperead('pathtofile/continent.shp');  idom = 2 ;
LAT = ncread('pathtofile/coords.nc','LAT');
coords_LAT = permute(LAT,[2 1]);
LON = ncread('pathtofile/coords.nc','LON');
coords_LON = permute(LON,[2 1]) ;
A = zeros(147,117) ;   

%read the filecontaining lat long information 
fileID = fopen('pat to file /Urbansites_lat_long.txt','r');
X = cell2mat(textscan(fileID,'%f  %f')) ;
X_lat = X(:,1); X_long = X(:,2) ;   
           if idom==2 %for UKdomain
           latlim=[49 60];lonlim=[-11 2];gspace=2;
           cellsize=0.05;
        end
[Z, refvec] = geoloc2grid(double(coords_LAT),double(coords_LON),A,cellsize);


ax = axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',latlim,...
'MapLonLimit',lonlim,'Grid','on',...
'MeridianLabel','on','ParallelLabel','on');
set(ax,'Visible','off')
geoshow(Z, refvec, 'DisplayType', 'texturemap');    
gridm('MLineLocation',2*gspace,'MLabelLocation',2*gspace,...   
   'PLineLocation',gspace,'PLabelLocation',gspace)
  geoshow(S(3,1).Y, S(3,1).X,'Color',[0 0 0],'Linewidth',1.5);%

            mycmap=load('MyColormaps');
            colormap(mycmap.mycmap);

 % the station locations.
   for i = 1:36
   h = geoshow(X_lat(i,:),X_long(i,:), 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker',...
  'o','Color','r','MarkerEdgeColor', 'r',...
  'MarkerFaceColor','r') ; 

    end

  caxis([0 60])
  tightmap
```

[image]

57.15736    -2.094278   -24.5380799

53.56292    -1.510436   -4.596925269

52.437165   -1.829999   7.030573015

52.511722   -1.830583   -9.955334856

53.80489    -3.007175   -3.861845799

50.73957    -1.826744   0.947924096

50.840836   -0.147572   9.580096269

Comment: Can you please show us how you tried it with `geoshow`, how the output looks, and what exactly you want to be different?

Comment: thanks.. i have added the code with my plot.. however, all the points are in red.. I now have an 3rd additional column in my dataset which is pollutant concentration. I need to plot the Station's latitude ,longitude  and concentration as markers but with differnet  colours  based on concentration and add a colorbar as well. Is there is a nicer way to do that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a vector `conc` containing the values of concentration, I think you can do something like this:

```
cm = colormap;

 for j=1:N

        indCol = ceil( size(cm,1) * conc(j) / max(conc) );


        if indCol==0 %cannot have index 0
            indCol=indCol+1; 
        end

        col = cm(indCol,:);


   h = geoshow(X_lat(j),X_long(j), 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker',...
  'o','Color',col,'MarkerEdgeColor', 'r',...
  'MarkerFaceColor','r') ; 
  end
```

And to add the colorbar, you have `colorbar`.

**EDIT**

If you have negative value, this could be a solution:

```
%before the for cycle, avoid to have negative values
shift=-min(conc);
conc = conc+shift;

%for cycle

%after the for cycle, rescale the colorbar
caxis([min(conc)-shift max(conc)-shift])
```

**BUT**

you also have to erase `'MarkerFaceColor', 'r'` otherwise they gonna be red no matter what!..

*So..*
Using the m_map toolbox and the data you gave here I obtained:

[image]

*My code*

```
A=[57.15736 -2.094278 -24.5380799;

53.56292 -1.510436 -4.596925269;

52.437165 -1.829999 7.030573015;

52.511722 -1.830583 -9.955334856;

53.80489 -3.007175 -3.861845799;

50.73957 -1.826744 0.947924096;

50.840836 -0.147572 9.580096269];

LAT=A(:,1);
LON=A(:,2);
conc=A(:,3);

latlim=[49 60];
lonlim=[-11 2];

B=zeros(147,117) ;   
cellsize=0.05;

figure; hold on; 
m_proj('mercator','lon',[lonlim(1) lonlim(2)],'lat',[latlim(1) latlim(2)])
m_grid('fancy')
m_gshhs_h('patch',[.5 .5 .5]);

cm = colormap;

shift=-min(conc);
conc = conc+shift;
 for j=1:numel(conc)

        indCol = ceil( size(cm,1) * conc(j) / max(conc) );


        if indCol==0 %cannot have index 0
            indCol=indCol+1; 
        end

        col = cm(indCol,:);


   m_plot(LON(j),LAT(j), '.','Color',col,...
  'MarkerFaceColor','r'); 
 end
colorbar
caxis([min(conc)-shift max(conc)-shift])
```

But I really do not think that you need to use m_map.. just make an equivalent code that works with geoshow

Comment: Hi Shamalaia, But what is cm stand for in your code ?

Comment: I get an error using your code as it doesnt recognise cm ??please help.. thanks

Comment: It still gives error, as cm is 83 x 3 , and my values are only 36..       Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. col = cm(indCol,:);

Comment: did you set `N=36` in the for loop?

Comment: Shamalaia..Yes i have set N already as 36.. It still gives the same error..

Comment: what's the value of `indCol` when you get the error? NaN?

Comment: indCol is -44.. It has been a negative number all the time

Comment: tell me if the edited code works, i do not have data to test it

Comment: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in Bias_Mapping (line 56)
        col = cm(indCol,:);

Comment: `shift=-min(conc);`?

Comment: It still doesnot work....col should have same dimensions as indcol.. with your code col has only 1 row with 3 columns.. so Matlab gives error as col show be 3 element vector for colouring the markers.. i tried to add j as dimension for col and indcol.. but it still doesnot work.. SSR

Comment: My conc values were changed due to the shift .. I am still getting all markers as same colour.. nothing different from my original plot above

Comment: I have added first few lines of my data as well..Please help.

Comment: I am doing it as                   h = geoshow(X_lat(j,:),X_long(j,:), 'DisplayType', 'Point', 'Marker', 'o','Color',col(j,:));

Comment: this has to work `geoshow(X_lat(j),X_long(j),'.','Color',col,'MarkerEdgeColor', 'r')`. If not just try to adapt my code to the use of geoshoe. if still do not work, google m_map

Comment: thanks.. it works with m_map ..but unfortunately doesnot work with geoshow.. not sure why